# How to automatically download an executable with Selenium and Firefox?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and C# to automate automatically downloading an executable when I click on a link in Firefox. Ideally, I'd like to execute the file as well but for now, I'd like to download it and execute it later. Here's what I have so far:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\Test");
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

When I click the link, it still shows the Save dialog but it does save it to my Test folder if I click Save. I'm using Firefox 21.
How do I ensure the Save dialog doesn't appear and the download happens automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/x-msdownload");

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile)
```