# How to test Print and Download functionality using Selenium WebDriver with Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, selenium-webdriver

In my test scenario, I click on the Print or Download button and I should check that the table from UI screen printed/downloaded correctly.

Do you have any ideas how to automate this test case?

I guess that using proxy, I can get the directory were my file will be saved? I use Selenium WebDriver+Proxy for FireFox and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Firefox you can manipulate the Firefox profile to automatically download files.  An example of this is here: [How to automatically download an executable with Selenium and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886207/how-to-automatically-download-an-executable-with-selenium-and-firefox?rq=1)

Sending a document to the print spooler, however, is a different kettle of fish.  These are actually performed by the operating system and are thus outside of Selenium's scope.  As far as I know, using a browser's Print Preview action is also not performed in Selenium WebDriver.  Testing printing from the browser will have to be performed manually.